# Why does output shows only 13 card on suit club. And not the rest of it ? Help anyone?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

Why does output shows only 13 card but only suit, club. And not the rest of it ? Help anyone ?  Is there something wrong with my loop.

```
public class deck { 

        public Card[] deck;  // field

        public deck() {
           deck = new Card[52]; // store into deck 
        }

        public void DeckCreation() {
            String[] suit = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };//Array for suit
            int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }; // Array for number

            for (int i = 0; i <suit.length ; i++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) { 
                    Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[i]);// Card instantiate
                    if (deck[i] == null) {
                        deck[i] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public void displayDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i <deck.length; i++) {
            if (deck[i] != null) {
                deck[i].display(); // display
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add the output of the program and the output you would expect from a correct program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <suit.length ; i++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) { 
        Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[i]); // Card instantiate
        if (deck[i] == null)
        {
            deck[i] = c; // Repeatedly trying to access index 0 to suit.length-1
        }
    }
}
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <suit.length ; i++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < number.length; n++) { 
        Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[n]); // Card instantiate

        // Using (i*number.length + n) will get you from index 0 to 51
        if (deck[(i*number.length + n)] == null)
        {
            deck[(i*number.length + n)] = c; // Accessing index 0 to 51
        }
    }
}
```

(0 * 13 + 0) = 0, (0 * 13 + 1) = 1, (0 * 13 + 2) = 2..

(3 * 13 + 0) = 39, (3 * 13 + 1) = 40, ..., (3 * 13) + 12 = 51..

Answer (score 0):

```
            Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[i]);// Card instantiate
```

This should be

```
            Card c = new Card(suit[i], number[n]);// Card instantiate
```